# mysql cursor is not open

Tags: mysql

Iam having a problem with following MySql stored procedure, when i try to run it both from console and through the application it gives a SQLException, saying cursor is not open, Can someone tell me why it does not get open?

```
 DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS DELETE_EXPIRED_GIFTS_SP$$
CREATE PROCEDURE DELETE_EXPIRED_GIFTS_SP()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE gift_id_val INT;
    DECLARE item_id_val INT;   
    DECLARE expiry_date DATETIME;
    DECLARE  no_more_gifts INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE  gift_items_cur CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT user_gift_id, item_id
        FROM user_gift
        WHERE status in (1,3);

    DECLARE  CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
    SET  no_more_gifts = 1;

    OPEN gift_items_cur;
        select FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows;
        the_loop: LOOP
            FETCH  gift_items_cur  INTO   gift_id_val, item_id_val;

            IF no_more_gifts=1 THEN
                    CLOSE gift_items_cur;
                    LEAVE the_loop;
            END IF;

            SELECT end_time INTO expiry_date FROM item WHERE item_id = item_id_val;

            IF expiry_date IS NOT NULL AND expiry_date <= UTC_TIMESTAMP()
                THEN UPDATE user_gift SET status = 5 WHERE user_gift_id = gift_id_val;
            END IF;

         END LOOP the_loop;
    CLOSE  gift_items_cur;
    END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

And the error iam getting here is,

```
  09:05:31,328 INFO  [STDOUT] FATAL: com.abc.gift.support.impl.GiftSupportImpl - ERROR: CallableSt
atementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call DELETE_EXPIRED_GIFTS_SP()}]; SQL state [2
4000]; error code [1326]; Cursor is not open; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cursor is n
ot open
```

Comment: **Please post the exact error message, not a paraphrase.**

Comment: HI, updated the question with the error messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
the_loop: LOOP
    :
    IF no_more_gifts=1 THEN
        CLOSE gift_items_cur;      <<< Number 1
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;
    :
END LOOP the_loop;
CLOSE  gift_items_cur;             <<< Number 2
```

It appears to me that you're closing the cursor *twice* here.

You close it the first time after your handler activates and `no_more_gifts` has been set to `1`. At that point you also exit the loop and then try to close the cursor *again.*

I'd suggest changing your inner `if` statement to be just:

```
IF no_more_gifts=1 THEN
    LEAVE the_loop;
END IF;
```

Comment: HI, iam not an expert of MYSql Stored Procedures, i ve seen in alot googled examples that this validation has been included. That made me to think it is a must requirement for Cursor related StoredProcedures. I ll remove it and let you know the results.

Comment: @bluelabel, if the label you're using is the one for the outermost block (stored procedure) then yes, you would need to close the cursor since you're basically exiting the whole lot. However, here the label you're using for `leave` is that of the _loop,_ so it will continue running after the `end loop` line and therefore try to close the cursor a second time.

Comment: Yes i got your point and guess what that changed worked. Thanks a lot for the help.